# What are the disadvantages of RBAC with DENY command?

Tags: access-control

RBAC implementations used by databases like Postgres or MongoDB have *additive* permissions. By additive, I mean that the user's permissions are the sum of all the permissions granted to them by their roles. Permissions may be granted or revoked to a role, but if any of a user's roles grants the permission, it is granted to the user.

Contrary to this approach, databases like SQL Server and neo4j allow permissions to be explicitly denied for particular roles. In this case, the permission is granted if at least one of the user's roles grants it *and* if *none* of their roles denies the permission.

The additive GRANT/REVOKE implementation seems to be more common in the wild than the GRANT/REVOKE/DENY implementation used by SQL Server, but the latter approach appears more flexible to me. What are the disadvantages of using the GRANT/REVOKE/DENY implementation (as opposed to GRANT/REVOKE)?

Comment: Chiefly, complexity of implementation…